# timestamp of 31/12/9999 23:59:29

Tags: jython

Please have a look at the description below and let me know why the timestamp for 
31/12/9999 23:59:29 is not 253402264799, but 253402261199.

Many thanks,

Huy

```
import datetime
d1 = datetime.datetime(1970, 1,1,10,0,0)  ; I am in zone time 10
d2 = datetime.datetime(1970, 1,2,23,59, 59)
print d2 - d1 --> 1 day, 13:59:59  
convert 1 day, 13:59:59 to sec
= 136799s  <-- (48 + 14) * 3600 - 1

d1 = datetime.datetime(1970, 1,1,10,0,0)
d2 = datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59)  
print d2 - d1 --> 2932896 days, 13:59:59 
convert 2932896 days, 13:59:59 to sec
253402264799sec <-- (2932896 * 24 + 14) * 3600 - 1

print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(253402264799) --> exception throw

print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(253402261199) --> 31/12/9999 23:59:59
```

Comment: One hour difference - daylight savings time?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is Time Daylight Saving. Zone 10 is 11 hours ahead in summer time.

Comment: But neither of these dates is in summer, is it? Can you expand?